# Abstract over int and double using num is broken with new Dart version

Tags: dart

The following code used to work in Dart 2.6 (very simplified example!):

```
T plus<T extends num>(T a, T b) => a + b;
```

Now it fails with: `A value of type 'num' can't be returned from method 'plus' because it has a return type of 'T'.`

Is there a way to abstract over `double`/`int` like intended in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are passing the `--no-implicit-casts` flag to the analyzer in order to get this error. The code is correct in the current Dart language, but it contains an implicit cast, so if you choose to disable those, the code will not be accepted.

The reason the code does not work is that the static type of `a + b` is `num` (both have type `T` which is only known to extend `num`, so they are treated as `num`, and `num.operator+` returns `num`), and the return type is `T` which may extend `num`.

So, the code does an implicit cast from `num` to `T` if you allow it.

To make the code compile even without implicit casts, you have to turn it into an explicit cast:

```dart
T plus<T extends num>(T a, T b) => (a + b) as T;
```

Comment: no-implicit-casts was turned on already, but now some code like that breaks with an upgrade of Flutter.

Comment: In that case the analyzer must have fixed a bug in their static type checker. I'm not familiar with the particular change, but the current behavior is definitely correct. The subtype relation is such that `T` is a subtype of `num`, and the static type of `a + b` is `num`, so it has always been an implicit downcast.

Comment: That‘s also what I think happened. We saw the issue today upgrading from Flutter 1.12 to 1.14. I thought that probably there was some “magic” involved so that Dart “knew” that there only two subclasses of num that would render the case valid in a closed world.

Comment: There is magic related to `int` and `double`, but it is very limited. It only really affects operators on an `int` receiver, where the result becomes that of the other operand's type (so `int` if both are `int` and `double`/`num` if the second operand is `double`/`num`). Everything else is just the normal type system.